# Validate one input between two inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I have javascript validation code. I want to validate one input between two inputs. More clearly,

if a text input entered and dropdown input remains unselected, the js should validate the input and form should be submitted
and if dropdown selected and text input not entered than dropdown should be validate but not text input and form should be submitted.
I have simple validation and new to this problem.

```
if(document.form.inputname.value==""){
alert("Please Enter Your Name");
return false;}

if (form.inputname2.selectedIndex==0){
alert("Please select Choice !");
return(false);}
```

Update : In simple words I want to validate one input at one time (note: second input is hide through css and show when user click on a link)
Now suppose user click link then first input will be hide and second show, but with my above code alert in action for both input. So how I can validate either first input or second input. Is this possible with javascript or jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $("#Submit").on("click", function () {

     var dVal= $('#dropdownId').find('option:selected').val();
     var txt= $('#textbox').val();

     if(dVal!=''&& txt==''){
       alert("Please Enter Your Name");
       retrun false;
     }
     else if(dVal==''){
        alert("Please select Choice !");
        return(false);
     }
      else{
           //put your form submit code here
       }
  });
```